# GROUP BY ONLY HAVING different values same field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to use a query to Group by if that column value different only as an example I have a table like this

```
First Name   Last Name        DOB


Nimal        Herath         1987/03/15
Kamal        Bandara          Null
sunil        Perera         1988/08/20
Kasun        Sandaruwan     1985/07/02
Nimal        Herath           Null
Kamal        Bandara          Null
Sunil        Perera         1988/08/20
Kasun        Sandaruwan     1997/03/10
```

So I need to get users who have Same First Name and Last Name and Same Date of birth including Null DOB

When I use Group by It is return users Who have Same Value But It will Not Return If one user's DOB is null and other one will have a value

My Result should be as follow

```
First Name  Last Name  DOB      Count

Kamal        Bandara   Null        2
Sunil        Perera    1988/08/20  2
Nimal        Herath     1987/03/15 2
```

I tried This Query

```
Select * From Users Group By FirstName,LastName,Dob HAVING Count(*) >1
```

This Will Return all Duplicate Users Who have same DOB and if both null but it will not return one have a dob and other one null

Comment: Show query what have you tried so far

Comment: Hint: assign 'null' to some other value

Comment: @Strawberry basically gave you the answer. I will add another hint: [IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `group by FirstName, LastName` only and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select 
  firstname, lastname, max(dob) dob, count(*) count
from users  
group by firstname, lastname
having 
  count(distinct dob) <= 1
  and
  count(*) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tNfakv1wnSUziGhDpq43B/1).
Results:

```
| firstname | lastname | dob        | count |
| --------- | -------- | ---------- | ----- |
| Kamal     | Bandara  |            | 2     |
| Nimal     | Herath   | 1987/03/15 | 2     |
| sunil     | Perera   | 1988/08/20 | 2     |
```

Comment: what happen if Dob will 000/00/00 instead of null

Comment: 0000/00/00 is not allowed as a datetime value.

Comment: yes but in my database there are some rows containing dob as 000/00/00

Comment: This means that the data type of DOB is VARCHAR. If you want `000/00/00` to be treated as null the replace `max(dob)` with `max(case when dob = '000/00/00' then null else dob end)`

Comment: Not working can you check this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tNfakv1wnSUziGhDpq43B/1#&togetherjs=sxAihlzVoN

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DOB`, count(*) as Count
FROM table
GROUP BY `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DOB`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select FirstName, LastName, max(dob) as dbo, count(*)
from Users
group by FirstName, LastName 
having count(distinct dob) <= 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf4b5343b7efa0b08fd7f572d0ad560a) is a db<>fiddle.